# string io and parsing

Tags: beginner, rust

To learn Rust, I tried to write a function that takes string input and then converts it to integers for a time calculation for a delay.

Is this approach ok? Have I made any mistakes? I kind of struggled with needing to do two separate error checks for the string. First for the parse result and second for the limiting the unwrapped value. I was hoping to combine the is_ok call and then unwrapped value check in one condition. Ran into some borrowing error messages and type problems.

```
use std::io;

fn read_time(message : &str, max : u64) -> u64 {
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        println!("{}", message);
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        let num = input.trim().parse::<u64>();

        if num.is_ok() {
            let n = num.unwrap();

            if n < max {
                return n;
            }
            else {
                println!("exceeded max value of {}", max - 1);
            }
        }
        else {
            println!("Need a number above 0 and less than {}", max);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    println!("Waiting Sample Program");

    let hours = read_time("Enter hours: ", 24);

    let minutes = read_time("Enter minutes: ", 100);

    let wait = hours * 60 + minutes;

    println!("Going to wait {} minutes", wait);

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::new(wait * 60, 0));

    println!("done.");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking if the parse succeeded and then unwrapping the result in two steps, you can combine the operations by using pattern matching instead. Here, an `if let` expression will do the job.

```
if let Ok(n) = num {
    // use `n` here
}
```

I also have some suggestions concerning style, based on the prevailing style in the community:

1. Don't put a space between an identifier and the colon that precedes a type (`message: &str` rather than `message : &str`).
2. Put the `}` and the `else` on the same line.

Additionally, considering the way you've written the prompt messages, it looks like there shouldn't be a newline after the prompt, so I suggest you change the `println!` that prints the prompt to a `print!`.

Here's the revised code:

```
use std::io;

fn read_time(message: &str, max: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        print!("{}", message);
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        let num = input.trim().parse::<u64>();

        if let Ok(n) = num {
            if n < max {
                return n;
            } else {
                println!("exceeded max value of {}", max - 1);
            }
        } else {
            println!("Need a number above 0 and less than {}", max);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Waiting Sample Program");

    let hours = read_time("Enter hours: ", 24);
    let minutes = read_time("Enter minutes: ", 100);
    let wait = hours * 60 + minutes;

    println!("Going to wait {} minutes", wait);

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::new(wait * 60, 0));

    println!("done.");
}
```

---

If you want to combine the result of `parse` with the range checking in a single operation, that's possible too. First, let's look at the "lazy" way, where both error situations will produce the same error message:

```
fn read_time(message: &str, max: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut input = String::new();

    loop {
        print!("{}", message);
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        let num = input.trim().parse::<u64>();

        if let Some(n) = num.ok().and_then(|n| if n < max { Some(n) } else { None }) {
            return n;
        }

        println!("Need a number above 0 and less than {}", max);
    }
}
```

Here, I'm using [`ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) to convert the `Result` to an `Option`, because I'm too lazy to define an error type that unifies the parse error and our new out-of-range condition. Then I'm using [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) to perform the range validation only if the parse succeeded. The closure returns `Some(n)` if the value is in range, or `None` if the value is out of range.

Instead of using `and_then`, we could also use the [`filter`](https://docs.rs/option-filter/1.0.1/option_filter/trait.OptionFilterExt.html#tymethod.filter) method provided by the `option-filter` crate. It takes a closure that returns a `bool`, and returns `None` if the closures returned `false`, or the original value otherwise.

```
if let Some(n) = num.ok().filter(|n| n < max) {
    return n;
}
```

---

And now, let's *not* be lazy and code this up properly. We'll need to introduce a type that can represent either a parse error, or an out-of-range condition.

```
use std::num::ParseIntError;

enum ReadTimeError {
    ParseError(ParseIntError),
    ValueOutOfRange,
}

impl From<ParseIntError> for ReadTimeError {
    fn from(e: ParseIntError) -> Self {
        ReadTimeError::ParseError(e)
    }
}

fn read_time(message: &str, max: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut input = String::new();
    let check_in_range =
        |n| if n < max { Ok(n) } else { Err(ReadTimeError::ValueOutOfRange) };

    loop {
        print!("{}", message);
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
        let num = input.trim().parse::<u64>();

        match num.map_err(ReadTimeError::from).and_then(check_in_range) {
            Ok(n) => return n,
            Err(ReadTimeError::ParseError(..)) => {
                println!("Need a number above 0 and less than {}", max);
            }
            Err(ReadTimeError::ValueOutOfRange) => {
                println!("exceeded max value of {}", max - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we have three cases to handle, so I'm using a `match` expression rather than an `if let` expression. I'm taking advantage of the fact that patterns can match "deeply" to match on two levels of enums at the same time. `Result` also has an [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then) method, and naturally, the closure must return a `Result`. I moved the closure out of line to keep the expression being matched on short enough.

---

Now, it's up to you to decide whether combining the two validations is worth the additional complexity or not! :)